# Why is Glorfindel's reputation showing up as only 101 while other people's reputation is much higher?

Tags: support, bug, reputation

The screenshot below indicates shows the rep of three different users ([myself](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/8/), [taylor.2317](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/15), [Glorfindel](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/4/)). The reputation for myself and [taylor.2317](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/15) is accurate, but the reputation for [Glorfindel](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/4/) seems like it hasn't updated at all since being awarded the association bonus (which [taylor.2317](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/15) and [I](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/8/) both were awarded too). [Glorfindel](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/4/) has already asked two question which have been upvoted:

[image: taylor.2317's and Glorfindel's reputation on this question]

Answer (score 6):

[Caching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/).

I created my Meta user fairly early, before I got any upvotes. (Meta users are only created when you first visit the Meta site.) I suspect you created yours later on, and my reputation will update eventually (IIRC it's updated once an hour).

As of this edit, my meta reputation is 293, just like my main reputation.

But the bug doesn't seem to be resolved; right now the meta reputation is off for many (most?) users, including yourself.

Comment: I do intend to accept this answer, but it currently says "you can accept this answer in 9 minutes" if I click the checkmark button. I wonder though, why your profile's rep is not updating but everyone else's profile rep is updating? Your profile's rep did update on the main site!

Comment: Regarding your last edit, let me say that the reputation seems to be updating very slowly for this site, both on the main site and the meta site (but especially for the meta site). This applies everywhere, including when I click "users". The only place where the reputation seems to be updating in real-time is on the Area51 leader board. I've also unaccepted this answer since caching **does not** seem to be the (only) problem here!