# How should I format a question correctly?

Tags: support

Please use [this answer](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/a/48/15) to this question to find guidance on how to post a really good question!

---

###### Please note: This is *just* guidance, not a rulebook.

Comment: It would be good if the body of the question was an actual question, with the current body made into a comment to the question.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist this would remove the table...

Comment: Hey there - it looks like this post is more of a Q&A of advice for editors, than it is a rigid set of requirements askers must adhere to. At this point in the beta, I'd be wary of over-heavily proscribing those kinds of requirements. Would you mind editing this post into a more neutral format, maybe as advice for editors? Either way - I've edited out the threat of suspension from your post.

Comment: @Slate Hi, is this okay now?

Comment: @taylor.2317 Much better, yes, in my opinion. Not sure I'd fully agree that the things in the associated answer are what make a question good - but that's for community discussion ;)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

### Abbreviations

The following abbreviations will be replaced:

| Abbreviation | Replacement |
| --- | --- |
| bc / cos / coz / cause | because |
| thx | thanks |
| soz | sorry |
| tho | though |
| btw | by the way |
| ofc | of course |

These abbreviations are allowed, but not necessarily encouraged:

| Abbreviation | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| SO | [Stack Overflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com) |
| SE | [Stack Exchange](https://www.stackexchange.com) |
| PA / PA.SE | [Proof Assistants](https://www.proofassistants.stackexchange.com) |
| TL ; DR | Too long ; didn't read (short descriptions) |
| IMO | In my opinion |

---

### Mentions

If someone has helped you, and you wish to mention them, type their name, and link their account, e.g. `[taylor.2317](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/taylor-2317` --> [taylor.2317](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/taylor-2317)

---

### Urgent Help Requests

The following terms (and alike) **will** be removed if found in a question:

- Please help
- Urgent!
- Can anyone help?
- Thanks in advance
- Hello everyone

---

### Homework

Find SO's restrictions on homework questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

---

###### If you need to add / change anything, please do feel free to [edit](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/48/edit). Only people with 500+ reputation can edit. If you can't edit, comment your suggested edit.

Comment: The rule about linking to accounts for mentions doesn't seem necessary to me. Usernames are distinguishable in most cases, and at least I don't find myself wanting to see the user profile when I see such a mention. In the case of [this meta post](https://proofassistants.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9/227), I'd want to go to the respective profile pages to observe the bug (so linking once per user is good), but you absolutely don't have to link *every* occurrence of each username in the body.

Comment: Hi @taylor.2317, could you replace `PR / PR.SE` with `PA / PA.SE` in your answer? (and maybe update the automatic replacement algorithm, if any?), because this latter abbreviation sounds more natural AFAICT, and furthermore it's the one chosen [in the small blue icon within the website's flair](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/users/flair/142.png).

Comment: @ErikMD Hi, thanks for spotting this error! I have updated the table accordingly :)

Comment: I'm very confused what this answer has to do with the question. The answer addresses some (fairly specific) aspects of formatting, not posting content.

Comment: @Wojowu edited :)